# Remove duplicates from array of strings in Javascripts

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have the following json array:

```
["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "bb"]
```

How to remove the duplicate values from it with javascript, so at the end I got:

```
["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array Try searching/googling before posting please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.filter()`:

```js
var arr = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "bb"];
var res = arr.filter(function(item, index){
  if(arr.lastIndexOf(item) === index){
    return true;
  }
}).sort(function(a, b){
  return a > b;
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: btw, it works only for truthy values, because of returning the item instead of `true` - and it changes the order.

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks for suggestion. It does now.

Comment: you could simply use indexOf and take the first without later sorting (which may change the unsorted original order ...)

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(_.uniq(["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "bb"]));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```